# Flex skew Object

Tags: apache-flex, distortion

I was wondering how to distort a Flex object like Panel so it looks like a trapezoid?

Comment: Skew is the wrong term; I think the correct term is distort or warp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you trying to do something like this? [Flex skewing](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=15_Geometry_6.html)

```
    private function skewit():void {
        var smat:Matrix = new Matrix();
        smat.b = Math.tan(50);
        var mat:Matrix = myobject.transform.matrix;
        mat.concat(smat);
        myobject.transform.matrix = mat;
    }
```

http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=15_Geometry_6.html

Answer (score -1):

If you're really serious about this stuff, you should write it in ActionScript and pick up the book *[Numerical Recipes](http://books.google.com/books?id=1aAOdzK3FegC&dq=numerical+recipes&printsec=frontcover&source=bn&hl=en&ei=FUw5S7nNGKKGlgfl48zpDg&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=12&ved=0CDgQ6AEwCw#v=onepage&q=&f=false)* and read the chapter on "Computational Geometry".  It will probably answer all your questions and more!  Have fun :)